# How to write while within a MYSQL insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to mySQL and PHP. I have a table that I want update with a value that is in an array. I guess I am making syntax error. Assuming my Table Fields are **Reg_no**, **Field1**, **Field2** ......
I am using:

```
$i=1;
$query=mysql_query("insert into tablename set 
Reg_no = '".$common->html_protect($_REQUEST['reg_num'])."'
while(fieldcount<=10)
{
echo ",";
echo field.$i='".$common->html_protect($_REQUEST[$field.$i]) ."'
}
");
```

Any suggestion please!

Comment: If you're just getting started, I suggest you learn `MySQLi` or `PDO` insead. `MySQL` is deprecated and is soon to be removed.

Comment: Take a look into prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you Amal I will definitely learn it. I will Change all code later. But I am in between of this thing and would like to proceed with it. Please

Comment: If you really want to build your query like that, build it outside of mysql_query into a variable, then pass the query variable into mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `mysql_query` is deprecated as I know.

Try learning [PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html). It is safer, and other advantages I guess.

Moreover, what your example is doing is, write **into** the mysql query, which is probably wrong. In the end, you will have a mysql query like :

```
insert into tablename set Reg_no = 'something' while(fieldcount<=10) { echo something else }
```

etc. , which does not make sense in MySQL. MySQL will not understand what `echo` is.

MySQL expects a query like `"INSERT INTO tablename(fieldname) VALUES ('the_value')"`;

So I guess what you are trying to do is run a mysql query, and echo something in the screen, like this:

```
$pdo->query("insert into tablename (field1,field2) values ('value1' , 'value2')");
while(fieldcount<=10)
{
echo "something";
}
```

and please note that above example is also not safe, if you are concerned about mysql injection.

So, my advice is, also learn about [prepared statements](http://pressedweb.com/tutorials/pdo-baby-steps-prepared-statements/).

### Edit:

If you want to run mysql queries in a loop, you can do something like this:

```
<?php

for($i=0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++)
{
 $thefield = "field".$i; // construct your field name
 $thevalue=$i; // construct your value. I guess this is where your $_REQUEST variables go.
 $pdo->query("insert into tablename($thefield) VALUES('$thevalue')"); // then run the necessary mysql query.
 echo "i inserted $thevalue for the field $thefield";
}

// and of course, for this case, you may not need a loop. You can insert multiple values at once, like this:
$pdo->query("insert into tablename (field1,field2,and_any_other_field) values ('value1' , 'value2' , 'value_for_other_field')"); // etc.
 ?>
```

for example.

Comment: Yes you are right that MYSQL does not understand what is echo and what is while but I want to know how can I use it within mysql query. I want each and every field value to be inserted by use of while loop.

Comment: oh. than you loop in php, and apply mysql command in each loop. editing the answer now.

Comment: I hope I could help. And I would reccomend following a tutorial, preferrably written for pdo, and later versions ( >5 ) of PHP.

Comment: I guess this will create 10 rows. I want to insert 10 values into single row.

Comment: Yes, the first example creates ten rows. Please see the very last function in my answer. it creates one row.

Comment: and please consider accepting an answer that helped you. this is what makes stackoverflow fun :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental flaws in your code.

First, you are trying to use echo inside a string, which just doesn't work. Either you print out text, then you use `echo`, or you concatenate a string using `.`

Secondly, you are mixing the MySQL `UPDATE` and `INSERT` syntaxes.

You are trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename SET field=value,field2=value2;
```

This is the syntax for `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tablename SET field=value,field2=value2;
```

If you want to use `INSERT`, you have to do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1,field2) VALUES (value1,value2)
```

You can generate the parts within the parantheses pretty easily using arrays and implode:

```
$fields = array();
$values = array();
$fieldcount = 1;
while ($fieldcount<=10) {
    $fields[] = $field.$i;
    $values[] = $_REQUEST[$field.$i];
}
```

This will generate two arrays, one containing all field names and one containing all values. Now we can convert them to usable strings:

```
$all_fields = implode(",", $fields);
$all_values = implode("','", $values);
```

The strings will now contain:

```
"field1,field2"
"value1','value2"
```

(The enclosing `''` in the second string are missing on purpose)

Now you can add these strings into your query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO (" . $all_fields . ") VALUES ('" . $all_values . "')";
```

This generated query string will look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO (field1,field2) VALUES ('value1','value2')"
```

This can be used directly with mysql_query.

BUT: As has already been pointed out, this is all deprecated, you should directly start with the new way.

We will keep the part with the arrays, they are still usefull with prepared statements.

```
$fields = array();
$values = array();
$placeholders = array();
$fieldcount = 1;
while ($fieldcount<=10) {
    $fields[] = $field.$i;
    $values[] = $_REQUEST[$field.$i];
    $placeholders[] = "?";
}
```

Now we need some strings again

```
$all_fields = implode(',', $fields); // resulting in "field1,field2" again
$all_placeholders = implode(',', $placeholders); // results in: "?,?"
```

Now we create the query string:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO (" . $all_fields . ") VALUES (" . $all_placeholders . ")"
```

resulting in:

```
"INSERT INTO (field1,field2) VALUES (?,?)"
```

Now we create the statement and execute it with the actual values

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); // assuming $conn is a valid DBO connection. mysqli is similar
$stmt->execute($values);
```

This will execute the prepared statement, placing all values from the `$values` array in the `?` placeholders.

(Notes: I haven't checked if $field.$i actually generates usable variable names, it's just copy&paste from your code)